# Ckeditor & Dropbox dynamic link issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, dropbox-api

I use [Dropbox gem](https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox) with my rails 3 app for hosting assets. Everything works fine except for when picture of file url is stored inside the cktext field. Dropbox generates links dynamycally and after a while links not working anymore, even though file is still connected to `Ckeditor::Asset` model and can be re-connected via editor for a while, but only untill dropbox regenerates link again.

Is there a way to fix it somehow?
I use ckeditor (= 3.7.3)

Comment: Is the problem here that the Dropbox links stop working? How are you getting the link?

Comment: Link are generated by Dropbox API. When requested with instance data, they work fine, but they expire when they kept in plaintext in the middle of html, which is what I need to do. I think wrapping them in javascript and requesting through AJAX may work...

Comment: Well if the problem is the expiration, it's likely because the 'url' method in the library you use calls /media: (def url @client.media(@path)["url"]) and the links returned by that endpoint do expire after four hours: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media You may want to use these instead: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares
https://www.dropbox.com/help/201